# computation of maclaurin series for the function improper integral

Tags: calculus

I need help with computation of maclaurin series for the function improper integral

$$f(x)= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\sin x}{x}$$

thank you.

Comment: Is this the integral you want to evaluate?

Comment: mhm mr.benghorbal

Comment: The dirichlet integration $ \int_0^{+\infty} \dfrac{ \sin x}{x}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: can you show me step by step??

Comment: http://wenku.baidu.com/view/bb9c8ffe910ef12d2af9e71a.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Write down the usual series $x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\frac{x^7}{7!}+\cdots $ for $\sin x$.
2. Divide every term of the series by $x$.
3. Integrate each term from $0$ to $1$.

You will get an ordinary numerical infinite series. That's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a sixth-degree maclaurin polynomial to calculate that improper integral, then 
wouldn't it be x-x^3/18+x^5/600 and plug x=1 and x=0 and then calculuate and you get
-581/10800?

if you use a fourth-degree macluarin polynomial to calculate that improper integral, then wouldn't it be x-x^3/18 and plug x=1 and x=0 and then calculuate and you get 17/18?

0/2i *x^2 is 0. so is 0/4i *x^4 and 0/6i * x^6.

can anyone correct me if im wrong?